# Stack error when running benchmarks (tasty-bench)

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I try to include some benchmarks in my Haskell package and running `stack bench` generates an error:

```
Benchmark benchmarks: RUNNING...
All
  Fibonacci numbers
    fifth:     OK (4.28s)
      247  ns ±  17 ns
    tenth:     OK (5.88s)
Completed 3 action(s).

Error: [S-7282]
       Stack failed to execute the build plan.

       While executing the build plan, Stack encountered the error:

       <stderr>: commitAndReleaseBuffer: invalid argument (cannot encode character '\956')
```

Here is the relevant part of the **cabal** file:

```
benchmark benchmarks
  type:                 exitcode-stdio-1.0
  main-is:              Main.hs
  hs-source-dirs:       benchmarks/
  Build-Depends:        base >= 4.7 && < 5
                      , tasty-bench
                      , hspray
  default-language:     Haskell2010
```

And here is the code:

```hs
module Main where
import Test.Tasty.Bench ( bench, bgroup, defaultMain, nf )

fibo :: Int -> Integer
fibo n = if n < 2 then toInteger n else fibo (n - 1) + fibo (n - 2)

main :: IO ()
main = defaultMain
  [ bgroup "Fibonacci numbers"
    [ bench "fifth"     $ nf fibo  5
    , bench "tenth"     $ nf fibo 10
    , bench "twentieth" $ nf fibo 20
    ]
  ]
```

I upgraded **stack** and I ran `stack clean`. I use the latest **lts** release of **ghc**. I'm on Windows.

Comment: relevant: https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/8118

Answer (score 0):

Running `chcp 65001` in the console before running `stack bench` solved this problem.